# fopen not work with XCode

Tags: c, text-files

The function `fopen(FILE *fp)` in XCode it's not working, I put the text file in the root directory, but not work, it's weird because, executing from terminal works fine, but executing from IDE not.

The sintax that I use it's this:

```
FILE *fp=fopen("name.txt", "r");
if(fp==NULL)
{
    printf("the text file can't be opened");
    exit(0);
}
else
    return fp;
```

And always return `NULL`.

Comment: When you execute from the IDE you must be executing in a different directory from `root`. Add `strerror(ernno)` to the `printf()` to discover the reason why `fopen()` fails.

Comment: @H2CO3 Running your program from the Xcode IDE, Xcode configuration to specify what the current working directory for opening a file in said-directory at execution-time has *everything* to do with this.

Comment: @H2CO3 sure it does :) maybe the question title isnt specific enough

Answer (score 28, accepted):

well what's the working directory when run via xcode?
by default IIRC it isnt set and that might be the difference between IDE and terminal.

-- set the working dir:

go to:
product > scheme > edit scheme...

there go to:
options tab and choose a working directory

Comment: +1: Xcode schemes are on of the many less-than-intuitive concepts for running a program under their IDE. It contains a wealth of options, including program arguments, working directory, etc. This answer drills directly to the OP's question if he wants to run his program from a specified work-dir, while also nudging him to see what else is available with schemes.

Comment: The solution was put the entire route, just like "/Users/User/Documents/Develop/file.txt" thanks for your help.

Comment: sure, that works too as you don't need thw working directory at all :) likely it is best too (IMO)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your root directory is not the working directory of your IDE. Either change the configuration to use your root directory as your IDE's working directory, or put name.txt in your IDE's working directory.